Lifetimes of &mut self inside Rust methods when asigning in an inner scope
The Context
I am trying to get wgpu to work with winit. I followed the winit v0.30 docs on how to create a window and am now trying to follow the learn wgpu tutorial that unfortunately uses wini v0.29 that has had a big redesign. I am new to Rust and the Rust book is not helping me for this one.
This is my main:
mod graphics;

use winit::application::ApplicationHandler;
use winit::event::WindowEvent;
use winit::event_loop::{ActiveEventLoop, ControlFlow, EventLoop};
use winit::window::{Window, WindowId};

use graphics::State;

#[derive(Default)]
struct App<'window> {
    window: Option<Window>,
    state: Option<State<'window>>,
}

impl<'window> ApplicationHandler for App<'window> {
    fn resumed(&mut self, event_loop: &ActiveEventLoop) {
        let window = event_loop
            .create_window(Window::default_attributes())
            .unwrap();

        self.window = Some(window);
        if let Some(win) = &self.window {
            self.state = Some(State::new(win));
        }
    }

    fn window_event(
        &mut self,
        event_loop: &ActiveEventLoop,
        window_id: WindowId,
        event: WindowEvent,
    ) {
    }
}

fn main() {
    let event_loop = EventLoop::new().unwrap();
    event_loop.set_control_flow(ControlFlow::Wait);

    let mut app = App::default();
    event_loop.run_app(&mut app);
}

This is the graphics module:
use pollster::FutureExt as _;

use wgpu::Backends;
use wgpu::Instance;
use wgpu::InstanceDescriptor;
use winit::{event::WindowEvent, window::Window};

pub struct State<'window> {
    surface: wgpu::Surface<'window>,
    device: wgpu::Device,
    queue: wgpu::Queue,
    config: wgpu::SurfaceConfiguration,
    size: winit::dpi::PhysicalSize<u32>,
    // The window must be declared after the surface so
    // it gets dropped after it as the surface contains
    // unsafe references to the window's resources.
    window: &'window Window,
}

I left out the implementations for the State since they are not important and quite long. They are just copyied from learn wgpu.
The Problem
The problem I have is when i try to bind to self.state in the if let in the main file. The rust-analyzer tells me that a lifetime may not live long enough since the assignment requires '1 to outlive 'window where '1 is the lifetime of &mut self.
Where I am at
To start with. I don't understand why there is an error anyways, I know what lifetimes are since I read the book and have watched several videos on yt but one thing that is rarely discussed in the resources i found is how lifetimes work with structs.

Please add a [mre] of the problem occuring and add the complete error message (by cargo check not your IDE).

I struggled with this exact problem a while back, I'm not sure I can fix your code snippet right away, but maybe my implementation will be useful
Full code can be found in my repository
This is the entry point similar to yours. https://github.com/laralex/my_web_cv/blob/main/src/bin.rs#L57
struct State<'window> {
   pub window: &'window winit::window::Window,
   pub webgpu: Rc<Webgpu>,
   pub webgpu_surface: wgpu::Surface<'window>,
   pub webgpu_config: wgpu::SurfaceConfiguration,
   /* omitted */
}

This is how initialization from winit starts
async fn new(window: &'window winit::window::Window) -> Self {
      let (webgpu, surface) = Webgpu::new_with_winit(window).await;
      let webgpu = Rc::new(webgpu);
      /* omitted */
      Self {
         window,
         webgpu,
         webgpu_surface: surface.surface,
         webgpu_config: surface.config,
         /* omitted */
      }
}

This is how I isolated initialization from winit as a function, where I pass winit::window by reference, then create owned wgpu device / queue and return them all together from the function
https://github.com/laralex/my_web_cv/blob/main/src/renderer/webgpu/mod.rs#L121
pub async fn new_with_winit(window: &winit::window::Window) -> ( Self, WebgpuSurface<'static> ) {
  use wgpu::rwh::{HasDisplayHandle,HasWindowHandle};
  let size = window.inner_size();

  let instance = wgpu::Instance::new(wgpu::InstanceDescriptor {
     backends: wgpu::Backends::all(),
     ..Default::default()
  });
  
  // # Safety
  // The surface needs to live as long as the window that created it.
  let surface = unsafe { instance.create_surface_unsafe(wgpu::SurfaceTargetUnsafe::RawHandle { 
     raw_display_handle: window.display_handle().unwrap().into(), 
     raw_window_handle: window.window_handle().unwrap().into(),
  }) }.unwrap();

  let adapter = instance.request_adapter(
     &wgpu::RequestAdapterOptions {
           power_preference: wgpu::PowerPreference::default(),
           compatible_surface: Some(&surface),
           force_fallback_adapter: false,
     },
  ).await.unwrap();

  let (device, queue) = adapter
     .request_device(&Utils::default_device_descriptor(), None)
     .await.unwrap();

  let config = wgpu::SurfaceConfiguration {
     /* omitted */
  };
  surface.configure(&device, &config);

  ( Self { device, queue }, WebgpuSurface{ surface, config } )

Then the event loops is launched like this:
#[cfg(feature = "win")]
pub async fn run() {
   use std::cmp::Ordering;

   use winit::{event::*, event_loop::ControlFlow, keyboard::*};
   log_init();
   let event_loop = EventLoop::new()
      .expect("Winit failed to initialize");
   let window = WindowBuilder::new()
      .with_inner_size(winit::dpi::PhysicalSize::new(800, 600))
      // .with_maximized(true)
      .with_title("WebGPU demos for Alexey Larionov's web CV")
      .build(&event_loop).unwrap();
   let mut state = State::new(&window).await;
   let window_ref = &window;
   let time_begin = SystemTime::now();
   event_loop.set_control_flow(ControlFlow::Poll);
   event_loop.run(move |event, elwt| {
      match event { /* omitted */ }
   });
   /* omitted */
}

